# C# code to insert values into a database not working

Tags: c#, sql

This is the button for inserting those fileds into my database, the field names and db connection works for any other tasks but somehow this button keeps telling me the insert failed"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        int answer;
        sql = "INSERT INTO Registration VALUES (@Student_ID,@Course_ID,@Section,@Start_Date,@End_Date,@Semester)";
        connection.Open();
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_ID", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course_ID", lstcourse.SelectedItem.ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", txtsection.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_Date", txtstart.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End_Date", txtend.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Semester", txtsemester.Text);

        answer = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Dispose();
        connection.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("You're awesome and added " + answer + " row to your registration");
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You screwed up");
    }
    /////////////////////////////////
}
```

```
This is the table:

Registration_ID float   Checked
Student_ID      float   Checked
Course_ID       float   Checked
Section         float   Checked
Start_Date      datetime    Checked
End_Date        datetime    Checked
Semester        nvarchar(255)   Checked
        Unchecked
```

Comment: You should catch the `Exception` instead. Then get the full error message from there.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.Please take time out for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com//tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com//help). You might also want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com//questions/how-to-ask). As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: You are not supplying the columns to insert into... for example: `INSERT INTO Registration(columnName, colName)Values(12,12)`... If you are adding all columns then your approach should work. From the looks of it you are not and hence the issue.

Comment: Why are the IDs `float`?  Also note that you are passing strings for all the columns and leaving it for something else to convert the data types.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can try this code

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new 
 SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString))
 {
        connection.Open();
        string sql =  "INSERT INTO Table(id,name,test) 
        VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection)) 
        {
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int).value = val;  
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = Name;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = Test;
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
```

}

Comment: I downvoted because theres no explanation as why the error occurs and why the OP code is wrong. How does this directly fix the OP issue?

Comment: you can just replace your the table name and attribute in string sql also the val,Name and Test :)

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow this button keeps telling me the insert failed

It would of been helpful if you could have posted the actual error from the `catch` statement. If you debugged the routine and specifically inspected the error message, you'd notice what was wrong.

**The primary issue of** the error is because you didn't supply the columns to insert into. If you supplied *all* columns upfront the insert statement would be satisfied and work just fine.

**Solution**

1. Either make sure all columns are accounted for in the insert statement.
2. Specify the columns you are inserting into.

Your table according to your post has **7** columns, you are only supplying **6** of them. When you using the syntax of `INSERT INTO TABLENAME VALUES()` you have to supply values for all columns, not just a select few.

On the other hand if you used the syntax of `INSERT INTO TABLENAME(columnName, columnName)VALUES(value, value)` you are fulfilling the requirements by supplying two columns along with their values.

**Side Note**:

- Look into `using` [statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to ensure objects are disposed of.
- Use `SqlParameterCollection.Add` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `AddWithValue`, it has to infer the data types and this could cause unintended results.
- When declaring your parameters, please specify/add the correct data type and length that matches the column data type and length on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Either modify your SQL statement to include the missing column:

```
INSERT INTO Registration VALUES (@Registration_ID,@Student_ID,@Course_ID,@Section,@Start_Date,@End_Date,@Semester)
```

or specify the columns that will be populated in your new row (assuming your Registration_ID field is an auto-identifier)

```
INSERT INTO Registration (Student_ID, Course_ID, Section, Start_Date, End_Date, Semester) VALUES (@Student_ID,@Course_ID,@Section,@Start_Date,@End_Date,@Semester)
```